# How do I use a SwiftUI TextField on a property of an optional?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
class MyEntity {
  var entityName = "My Name"
}
```

I've got a view model:

```
final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var myEntity: MyEntity?
}
```

In my view:

```
struct EntityDetailsView {
  @StateObject var vm = MyViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    TextField("Entity Name", text: $vm.myEntity.entityName) //Error here
  }
}
```

I get the error: `Value of optional type 'MyEntity?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'entityName' of wrapped base type 'MyEntity'`

Xcode suggests I use '?', so I change it to `$vm.myEntity?.entityName`
But that just changes the error to: `Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Binding<MyEntity?>'`

I tried avoiding the issue by making myEntity non-optional, but that just leads to other problems as there's no way to statically initialize it so the app just crashes on launch. So how do I get my optional to work with TextFields?

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
struct EntityDetailsView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = MyViewModel()
    
    

    private var ourEntityName: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get { 
                 vm.myEntity?.entityName ?? "" 
            } set { newValue in
                 vm.myEntity?.entityName = newValue  
            }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Entity Name", text: ourEntityName)
    }
}
```

The issue is that having optionals being displayed can get messy, as they can be `nil`, so we have to design around that. The main elements of it are:

1. `get`

Simply, it puts `vm.myEntity?.entityName`, or if that value is `nil`, it returns `""`.

2. `set`

Here, when `ourEntityName` is changed, it sets the `entityName` we are worried about to that value.

We can use `ourEntityName` in the `TextField`.

Note that you can't just do something like `TextField("Entity Name", text: $vm.myEntity?.entityName ?? "")` because the text would not be `Binding`. The way I've done it makes it work as `Binding`. Additionally, `""` can obviously be replaced as desired.

Comment: is there a cleaner way to do this as this is cumbersome